# AutoMapper is not mapping ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am searching a knowledge how to properly configure AutoMapper to Include `ICollection` types mapping also.

Take a look at example below. There are some entities with sample names:

```cs
    public abstract class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Foo Item { get; set; }
    }
    public class Baz : Bar
    {
        public new virtual Foobar Item { get; set; }
    }
    public class Zoo : Baz
    {
        public new virtual Foobarbaz Item { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class Foo
    {
        public ICollection<Bar> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Foobar : Foo
    {
        public new ICollection<Baz> Items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Foobarbaz : Foobar
    {
        public new ICollection<Zoo> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

and now i would like to map `Foobarbaz` to `Foo` including `ICollection<Zoo> Items` map to `ICollection<Bar> Items` is it possible to configure AutoMapper to map like that in one line like `Mapper.Map<Foo>(foobarbaz);`

I tried i.a. configure like that

```cs
            Mapper.CreateMap<Foobar, Foo>()
                        .Include<Foobarbaz, Foobar>();      
            Mapper.CreateMap<Foobarbaz, Foobar>();      
            Mapper.CreateMap<Baz, Bar>()
                .Include<Zoo, Baz>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Zoo, Baz>();
```

with no success

actually working solution i found is to firstly map `Foobarbaz` into `Foo` and then using Linq map Items like below:

```cs
            Foo foo = Mapper.Map<Foo>(foobarbaz);    
            foo.Items = foobarbaz.Items.Select(f => Mapper.Map<Bar>(f)).ToList();
```

---

Finally I would like to achieve something which allows me to return base information (described by `Foo` class properties) no matter which nested type will I have.

Therefore I assumed I could override an abstract function defined in `Bar` that would return the parent of the Item list. For example having object of type `Zoo` by calling overriden function I'll return mapped its parent of class `Foobarbaz` to `Foo` with also mapped Items from `Zoo` to `Bar`.

I don't think it's stupid, and as I said before.. I had working solution but I'd like some advice on how to make it even better.